# How do I log in to a site that uses HTTPS via Python?

Tags: python, authentication, https

All in the title. I do not know how I would go about logging into an HTTPS site via Python. I am relatively new, however, but I could not find any documentation on how to perform such an action.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: HTTPS support is only available if the socket module was
>   compiled with SSL support.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("ccc.de")
c.request("GET", "/")
response = c.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
# => 
# 200 OK
# <!DOCTYPE html ....
```

To verify if SSL is enabled, try:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.ssl
<function ssl at 0x4038b0>
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection